# requestLocation() через интервал - CLLocation

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Для экономии энергии, учитывая `desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters` Хочу сделать запрос на локацию `requestLocation()` после определенного промежутка времени. По логике это должно уменьшить потребление батареи.

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
  self.requestLocation()
}
```

Тут проблема, `requestLocation()` вызывается, `didUpdateLocations` тоже, но по `CLLocation` меняется раз в 2 минуты. Все остальное время показатели идентичны по локации, меняется только время. 
P.S. Использую симулятор и Freeway Drive

```
<+37.42467819,-122.22918858> +/- 5.00m (speed 35.86 mps / course 311.13) @ 29.01.2018, 12:00:18 Восточная Европа, стандартное время
<+37.42467819,-122.22918858> +/- 5.00m (speed 35.86 mps / course 311.13) @ 29.01.2018, 12:00:24 Восточная Европа, стандартное время
<+37.42467819,-122.22918858> +/- 5.00m (speed 35.86 mps / course 311.13) @ 29.01.2018, 12:00:29 Восточная Европа, стандартное время
```

Если же запускаю `requestLocation()` без задержки, таймера и прочего все работает правильно.

> Есть ли какие-то решения для обновлении локации через короткое время ?

Comment: А почему бы не гасить обновление локации а в нужный момент (+5 мин) включать?

Answer (score 0):

Можно по времени включать обновление места положения:

[image: обновление по времени]

После выполнения didUpdateLocations выключать обновления и запускать таймер снова:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

это же можно выполнить с помощью обычного таймера